# web speech api safari

Tags: ios, browser, safari

I have been looking into the web speech api. The web speech api works in chrome and mozilla but I can not figure out if the web speech api, for converting speech to text is already working for safari 11. Apple said this function would be included in safari 11 but I could not find any information whether they implemented the web speech api for speech to text conversion in safari 11. So my question is if anybody knows whether speech to text conversion is working for safari 11 already?

Comment: here you can find the information apple published, they say text to speech and "vice versa" would be supported: https://developer.apple.com/safari/features/

Comment: I'm looking as well;  Safari says web speech api works both ways (text -> voice AND voice to text). The chart here shows what is  actually supported. text -> voice works, but not the other way.:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Answer (score 1):

For Safari, the Web Speech API refers to text to speech for accessibility purposes. Unfortunately there is no built in way to convert speech > text in Safari.

However, their text > speech api is accessible through `speechSynthesis`.

You must first create an instance of a `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` to pass to the `speechSynthesis.speak()` method.

```
var x = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
x.text = "hello";
speechSynthesis.speak(x);
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis